# insert and select chinese word from oracle database

Tags: database, oracle

I am trying to insert chinese word into oracle database but anyhow it failed to display properly , here is my setting for database

```
SQL> select * FROM nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET';


PARAMETER
------------------------------
VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET
AL16UTF16

SQL> select * FROM nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';

PARAMETER
------------------------------
VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NLS_CHARACTERSET
AL32UTF8
```

The chinese character will be ".." when I copy/paste into my SQLPLUS to run the query.
The version I using is Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit.
Any hints ?

Comment: What does «character will be ".." when I copy/paste» mean? Are you on Windows or on Unix?

Comment: Unix server.. My mistake here . I copy / paste my query into SQLPLUS.

Comment: And does the character look fine when you paste it? Can you run e.g. `echo 世並問` from a regular bash console?

Comment: It may depend on your client NLS settings.

Answer (score 0):

There can be several issues:

1) The characters can not be stored in the database.

2) The characters may be converted to something else depending on client language settings.

3) The tool you are working with cannot display the characters.

--

1) Check the byte values of the character as it is stored in the table.

```
select dump(column) from table where ...
```

The dump function will show the byte values and you can check if the correct bytes are stored in the column.

2) Check the NLS_LANG setting on your client.

3) If the correct bytes are stored in the table and they are not being converted to something else due to a NLS_LANG mismatch between server and client then maybe your tool cannot display the characters correctly. I'm pretty sure SQLPlus has a very limited interface. Maybe SQL Developer can display a wider range of characters.